# How to get value within nested array using map or filter by ID

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

[image]

I have an array of orders as seen in the above photo. What I want to do is get a **product** order count and **quantity** by **product id(bmJr7AkG)**.

I want to get from the orders array, how many times a product has been ordered and the quantity of the product ordered(data array) in each case.

How can I do this using the filter or map methods.

```
this.ds.getAllOrders().pipe(
 map((orders: any) => orders.forEach(item => 
   item.cart.filter(cart => cart.product.id
            === "bmJr7AkG")
            ))
        ).subscribe(items => console.log(items))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of orders by id, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```
this.ds.getAllOrders().pipe(
  map(orders =>
    orders.reduce((total, order) => {
      return total +
        order.cart.filter(item => item.product.id === 'bmJr7AkG')
                  .map(item => item.data.quantity) // map to quantity
                  .reduce((sum, qty) => sum + qty, 0); // sum the quantities
    }, 0)
  )
).subscribe(count => console.log(count))
```

Using `forEach` is unnecessary as it does not produce any results, it simply applies the action on your items. You could have used `map` to map each order to a count and then summing the values, but it is easier to just use `reduce` to produce this sum while iterating on your items.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be able to get the number of orders in which the product('bmJr7AkG') is found. But, it doesn't take into account the quantity ordered in an order. Let say there 4 orders, and in one of the orders, this particular product was ordered 2 times, I should expect to get something like 5 orders. But with the present answer, I get just 4. How can I map that to the ``cart.data.quantity`` property. thanks again.

Comment: @LearnToday, if the property quantity is cart.data.quantity, you can use an inner reduce to sum on it too, see the answer, I udpated it